# Account unlock is not happening even after unlock_time

Tags: ubuntu, security, pam, account-restrictions

I want to lock user account after 3 failed attempts, I am following this [guide](https://www.linuxtechi.com/lock-user-account-incorrect-login-attempts-linux/). I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (for jumphost purposes only). However, the automatic unlock is not happening after 10 minutes. To unlock I have to manually execute the following command

```
sudo pam_tally2 -u devops --reset
```

Comment: why do you believe that it should unlock after 10 minutes?

Comment: unlock_time=600 –> It means account will remain locked for 10 minutes or 600 seconds
Though it is not official documentation, this is what i understood from the link which i followed. It will auto unlocked